# Writing a Splunk Query - Unique Count of Initial Access Key Usage from Cloudtrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, splunk, splunk-query

I have a use case to write a splunk query to display in a line or area chart the unique and initial AWS access key usage by IAM users in our org trending for the past year. Management want to be able to visually show increased cloud adoption numbers over time. Any ideas on how to display this? I feel like I'm almost there with stats but not quite.

index=blah sourcetype=blah user_type=SAMLuser | stats earliest(eventTime) by userIdentity.userName

This almost gets me there, but it won't depict the stats in a pretty line chart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start.  That `stats` command gets you the initial key usage for each user.  To get a trend, plot the number of keys used each day over time.

```
index=blah sourcetype=blah user_type=SAMLuser 
| stats earliest(eventTime) as _time by userIdentity.userName
| timechart span=1d dc(userIdentity.userName) as Users
```

The `as _time` clause ensures `timechart` has the _time field it needs.